# Issues opening project file in tfs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open a project/website for edit in TFS and I'm having a lot of issues. TFS is proving a learning curve for me...

I'm trying to access files in the 'forms' root...

These are the steps I’m taking…

Right-click on ‘forms’ and click on “Get Latest Version”
[image: 1]

Then this screen pops up…

[image: 2]

When I hit OK, then I right click again, and click “Check Out for Edit”
[image: 3]

I hit “Check Out” 
[image: 4]

Then to open the site, I go to File > Open > Web Site… 
[image: 5]

Then the File System comes up… I selected ‘forms’, as you suggested… 
[image: 6]

Once it opens, I see this… 
[image]

I double-click on ‘Default.aspx’, and this comes up… 
[image: 8]

When I view in Browser, this is the screen I get… 
[image: 9]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with TFS...?  It looks like you're getting the code fine, it's just that you're having trouble building and running it...  (In particular, it looks like you're trying to run your ASP.NET 4.0 app with a ASP.NET 2.0 app pool.)

Comment: Maybe that's the issue... opening 4.0 in the 2.0 pool... how is that fixed?

Comment: And what it has to do with TFS is that the project is a TFS project... I am having trouble opening it in Solution Explorer so I can edit the file and debug it, but instead, what I get is the results you see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best way to accomplish what I was trying to do. This was after several hours of trial/error...

**Open a Web Site…**

[image: Open a Web Site]

**Select Source Control Project…**

[image: Select Source Control Project]

**Choose the site root.**

[image]

**It may prompt you to receive a local copy.  Do this.**

[image]

**If it asks you to change frameworks, say no.**

[image]

**In the Solution Explorer, a new .sln file should be generated, with properly bound files:**

[image]